# Finite morphism $f:X \to \mathbb{P}_k^n$ is surjective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-schemes

Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional projective $k$-scheme and let $f: X \to \mathbb{P}_k^n$ be a finite morphism.

> 1. Is $f$ necessarily surjective?
> 2. If not, then what else do we need to impose such that $f$ is surjective?

**What I tried:**

1. If $f$ is dominant, then $f(X)$ is dense and closed and hence equal to $\mathbb{P}_k^n$. Now $f$ is dominant if and only if $f(X)$ contains the generic point of $\mathbb{P}_k^n$.
2. Since $f$ is finite, $f(X)$ is closed and thus by the irreducibility of $\mathbb{P}_k^n$ 
   $$
   f(X) = \mathbb{P}_k^n \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \operatorname{dim}f(X) = \operatorname{dim}\mathbb{P}_k^n = n
   $$
   Now if finite morphism do (to some extent) preserve dimensions, then this could be an approach.

Comment: Of course finite morphisms preserve dimension. Here is a reference: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0ECG

Comment: @MooS I know that reference, but it does not help me since I don't know if $f(X)$ has dimension $n$. If it does, then we're done.

Comment: By the reference $f(X)$ has the same dimension as $X$. I do not see the problem.

Comment: The reference says: $dim(X)= dim(Y)$ if $f$ is surjective.

Comment: I am pretty sure that $X \to f(X)$ is surjective.

Comment: @MooS Yeah, I actually did *not* thought about that, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X_0\subset X$ be an irreducible component of $X$ of dimension $n$ (you didn't suppose $X$ irreducible!).  Its image $Y:=f(X_0)\subset \mathbb P^n_k$ is irreducible and closed ( because $f$ is finite and thus closed).
Since $f\vert X_0:X_0\to Y$ is finite and surjective we have $n=\operatorname {dim}(X_0)=\operatorname {dim} (Y)$.
But now the inclusion of irreducible varieties $Y\subset \mathbb P^n_k$ **both of dimension $n$** forces $f(X_0)=Y=\mathbb P^n_k$, so that *a fortiori* $f(X)=\mathbb P^n_k$, i.e. $f$ is surjective as desired.

Comment: Actually there is no reason to pass to an irreducible component of $X$. Any $n$-dimensional closed subset of projective $n$-space - irreducible or not - is equal to projective $n$-space and thus a fortioti irreducible.

Comment: @MooS: Yes but what you you write  is not a standard  result stated in books and its  proof would probably be in the spirit of what I wrote.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Why is the image of $X_0$ again irreducible?

Comment: This is pure topology: the image of an irreducible topological space under a continuous map is irreducible.

Comment: True, now that I wrote it down, it is clear! Thank you.